# 文字列処理の問題

Tags: python

以下のプログラムがわかりません。

`x='Department of Intelligent Systems Engineering'` を代入する。
`y` に任意の文字列を入力する。
文字列 `y` の値が文字列 `x` に含まれているか２回確認せよ。
含まれていたら、文字列 `x` の文字列 `y`より後ろの文字列を出力する。
（出力した結果を `x` に代入し、２回目の検索を行う）。
該当しなければ`'NULL'` という文字列を出力せよ。

yを'g'とするときの実行結果:

１回目は `'ent Systems Engineering'`
２回目は `'ineering'`

Comment: 「わかりません」と宣言するだけでは貴方の学習や理解・成長につながらないでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事 [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を参考に、分からないながらも対処しようとして何かを調べたこととか、作成しようとしたプログラムの断片だけでもあればどんなものかといったことを追記して、助言や回答を得やすくした方が良いでしょう。ちなみにこちらのページ [組み込み型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html) の内容を調べたり、それを切っ掛けに検索を続けたりすると理解や解決につながると思われます。

Comment: 「２回確認せよ。」とはどういう意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
x='Department of Intelligent Systems Engineering'
y = input("入力しろ:")
for i in range(2):
    try:
        j = x.index(y)
        x = x[j+len(y):]
        print(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("NULL")
        exit()
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。for文の中はifやelseを使用してもいいんですか

Comment: ValueErrorとなる条件をif文で作ることも可能かと思います。ただ、index(y)で発見できないケースに対応するならValueErrorを使っとくのが自然だと考えました。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132718/best-way-to-handle-list-indexmight-not-exist-in-python